# very strange jboss tools configuration problem

Tags: eclipse, jboss-tools

I have installed Jboss Tools for my Eclipse Galileo.

I have enabled **JSF capabilities** for my project but I am still not able to navigate in my jsp pages like I can navigate in IntelliJ Idea when I enable facelets.

I want to remove the JSF capabilities using Jboss Tools and add them again, but when I go to *Configure - Jboss Tools - Add JSF* capabilities there is no option to **remove** and I cannot **add** them again because it says that *current project is already registered*...

Can you help me with a workaround please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Right click project, properties.
Find facets and see if remove and adding jsf facet works for you.